# Beginner-Level: What if a Objectvariable reference to Instance?

Tags: vb.net

If have a problem to understand the second line of the following code:

```
Dim locSecondClass As New SecondClass
Dim locFirstClass As FirstClass = locSecondClass

Public Class FirstClass
    Public Overridable Function aFunktion() As String
        Return "First Class"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class SecondClass
    Inherits FirstClass
    Public Overrides Function aFunktion() As String
        Return "Second Class"
    End Function
End Class
```

What is in `locFirstClass`? If its type is `FirstClass` but `locSecondClass` is copied into it? Is `Inherits First Class` also copied into `locFirstClass`? What would happen if class `SecondClass` would have a function/method that doesnt exist in `FirstClass`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no copying involved, instead locFirstClass is referencing the same instance as locSecondClass. However locFirstCLass only knows that it is referencing a FirstClass so can only call methods present on FirstClass.

However as aFunktion is declared `Overridable` The program ditermines at runtime what the actual type is of the object and calls that method in this case returning `"Second Class"`

Answer (score 0):

`FirstClass` is base class of `SecondClass`.
It will never be the case that something available in `FirstClass` (which is not private), is not available in `SecondClass`.